# What are the points of simple algebraic groups over extensions of $\mathbb{F}_1$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, field-with-one-element

The "field with one element" $\mathbb{F}_1$ is, of course, a very speculative object.  Nevertheless, some things about it seem to be generally agreed, even if the theory underpinning them is not; in particular:

- $\mathbb{F}_1$ seems to have a unique extension of degree $m$, generally written $\mathbb{F}_{1^m}$ (even if this is slightly silly), which is thought to be in some sense generated by the $m$-th roots of unity.  See, e.g., [here](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/the-f_un-folklore) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element#Field_extensions) and the references therein.
- If $G$ is a (split, =Chevalley) semisimple linear algebraic group, then $G$ is in fact "defined over $\mathbb{F}_1$", and $G(\mathbb{F}_1)$ should be the Weyl group $\mathcal{W}(G)$ of $G$.  For example, $\mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$ should be the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$.  (See also [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272498/analogies-supporting-heuristic-weyl-groups-algebraic-groups-over-field-with-o/272623?noredirect=1#comment674838_272623).)  I think this is, in fact, the sort of analogy which led Tits to suggest the idea of a field with one element in the first place.

These two ideas taken together suggest the following question:

> What would be the points of a semisimple (or even reductive) linear algebraic group $G$ over the degree $m$ extension $\mathbb{F}_{1^m}$ of $\mathbb{F}_1$?

My intuition is that $\mathit{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ should be the [generalized symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_symmetric_group) $\mu_m\wr\mathfrak{S}_n$ (consisting of generalized permutation matrices whose nonzero entries are in the cyclic group $\mu_m$ of $m$-th roots of unity); and of course, the adjoint $\mathit{PGL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ should be the quotient by the central (diagonal) $\mu_m$; what $\mathit{SL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ should be is already less clear to me (maybe generalized permutation matrices of determinant $\pm1$ when $m$ is odd, and $+1$ when $m$ is even? or do we ignore the signature of the permutation altogether?).  But certainly, the answer for general $m$ (contrary to $m=1$) will depend on whether $G$ is adjoint or simply connected (or somewhere in between).

I also expect the order of $G(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ to be $m^r$ times the order of $G(\mathbb{F}_1) = \mathcal{W}(G)$, where $r$ is the rank.  And there should certainly be natural arrows $G(\mathbb{F}_{1^m}) \to G(\mathbb{F}_{1^{m'}})$ when $m|m'$.  (Perhaps the conjugacy classes of the inductive limit can be described using some sort of Kac coordinates?)

Anyway, since the question is rather speculative, I think I should provide guidelines on what I consider an answer should satisfy:

- The answer need not follow from a general theory of $\mathbb{F}_1$.  On the other hand, it should be generally compatible with the various bits of intuition outlined above (or else argue why they're wrong).
- More importantly, the answer should be "uniform" in $G$: that is, $G(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ should be constructed from some combinatorial data representing $G$ (root system, Chevalley basis…), not on a case-by-case basis.

(An even wilder question would be if we can give meaning to ${^2}A_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ and ${^2}D_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ and ${^2}E_6(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ when $m$ is even, and ${^3}D_4(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ when $3|m$.)

Comment: Imho S_n  is  GL not SL  over F_1. Though there are different opinions. I would think An is analog of SL or  PSL or PGL. For example for embeding Sn to GL as permutation matrices goes to GL , moreover representation theory of SL is more complicated than GL so it is not like Sn

Comment: @AlexanderChervov $\mathfrak{S}_n$ can be both $\mathit{SL}$ and $\mathit{GL}$ over $\mathbb{F}_1$, which makes perfect sense if the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_1$ is of order $1$, and certainly follows both from the "Weyl groups are points over $\mathbb{F}_1$" principle and from the description I suggest for $\mathit{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_{1^m})$ in general.

Comment: [SL SL] = SL - that holds for every F_q and it is completely algebraic relation, so it would be strange if it is not true for F_1 , is not it ? So it contradics SL(F_1) = S_n, since [S_n S_n] = A_n and quite perfectly agrees with [GL GL] = SL , so for q=1 we have: [S_n S_n] = A_n. That is just my imho. It might be I am wrong. Glad to hear contr-arguments,

Comment: Your suggestion  is very interesting  -  that GL(F_1^n) is set of "permutation matrices" with  roots of unity coefficients.  Very interesting ! What is Frobenius map ? It is just natural x->x^p ? Can we check Lang-Steiberg(?) like theorem that G = G^{-1} F(G) ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I don't find it strange at all: lots of purely group-theoretic facts admit exceptions when they are evaluated over the points of algebraic groups over small finite fields, and $1$ is certainly small. For example, $G_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is simple for every $q$ except $2$, which is exactly the sort of phenomenon you mention. I think a pure group-theoretic view is simply not good to approach algebraic groups (which have a richer structure). Also, if you want $G(\mathbb{F}_1)$ to always be simple, you end up with $B_n$, $C_n$ and $D_n$ to have the same (contd.)

Comment: By the way Weyl groups can be realized as "permutation matrices" with +-1 signs and other case as with even number of +1 (if I remember corectly). So in your ideology Weyl group is $GL(F_{1^2})$. Does it have conceptual understanding ?

Comment: (contd.) set of points over $\mathbb{F}_1$, because they will all end up being $\mathfrak{A}_n$. Anyway, I don't know, but I think we should really stick to the principle that "points over $\mathbb{F}_1$ give the Weyl group". For your other questions, I really don't know, but I think $\mathbb{F}_1$ probably doesn't behave *too much* like the usual finite fields, and I'm not convinced there is anything like a Frobenius (or even a Galois group).  Probably best not to speculate too much unless a coherent answer can be made.

Comment: Simplicity is different condition - it does not seems to be given by identity. What I have in mind - that GL is something which has "good reduction" at all points including F_1 .

Comment: See Lorscheid, Theorem 3.14 of his 2nd blueprints paper at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1324.pdf.  He describes $G(F_{1^2})$ in his framework, at least.  For $n > 2$... why not email Lorscheid?

Comment: @Marty Thank you, this is indeed interesting. The result in question states that $G(\mathbb{F}_{1^2}$ is the extended Weyl group, which is very nice; unfortunately, I seem to understand that there are conditions on $G$, and also that $G(\mathbb{F}_1)$ is merely a subgroup of the Weyl group, but the author explains why he thinks the latter is unavoidable.

Comment: Perhaps the speculative theory of "spetses" is relevant here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01237357 My rough understanding is that the idea of spetses is to treat all complex reflection groups like the Weyl group of some kind of analog of a reductive algebraic group.

Comment: @SamHopkins I feel that spetses are more or less the answer to the "opposite" question (starting with something which is more or less a Weyl group, we try to construct something like an algebraic group; whereas here I try to go in the opposite direction), but they are indeed worth mentioning. If you know something about them, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/247718) would be a place to post a short summary, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: I see what you mean about "opposite" direction. I should also mention, however, a recent interesting development- the definition of "cyclotomic root system" here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03779. If you could attach such a root system to your generalized algebraic group, then maybe you could extract the generalized Weyl group out of it.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272698/what-are-the-points-of-simple-algebraic-groups-over-extensions-of-mathbbf-1#comment674947_272698), neither $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_2)$ nor $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_3)$ is its own commutator subgroup, so the relation probably cannot be said to be "completely algebraic" in your sense.  (It is also amusing, though surely irrelevant, that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb F_2) = \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb F_2) = \operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb F_2)$ is $\mathrm S_3$.)

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer - just opposite -   some additional requirments which 
good answer may satisfy and further comments.

**0)** *Parabolic subgroups should also be defined.*
I mean good definition should also come with definition of parabolic subgroups.
For example for $S_n$, it seems natural to consider $S_{d_1}\times ... \times S_{d_k}$ as parabolics.

**1)**
*Element count should be compatible with "known" (= widely agreed)
zeta-functions of P^n (and also Grassmanians, Flags).*
I mean one can define P^n, Grassmanians, Flags in a standard way just by quotients of G/Parabolic. So one should get number of points for such manifold over $F_{1^l}$, hence one can write a standard Weil's zeta function.
For example for S_n for  Grassamnian $|S_n/(S_k\times S_{n-k}) | = n!/(k!(n-k)!)$.
Requirment: zeta should agree with the "known" one (for example s(s-1)...(s-n+1) for P^n).

**2)**
*Structure of representation theory of such groups should be similar to G(F_q).*
For example for GL(F_1^l) one may expect that similar structure as in Zelevinsky theorem (see [MO272686](https://mathoverflow.net/a/272686/10446)), i.e. all representations (for all "n" GL(n)) organized into Hopf algebra using induction and restriction should be isomorphic to several copies of the same Hopf algebra for S_n, each copy for each cuspidal representation.
Interesting question how many cuspidals will one have for fixed GL(n,F_1^l) ?

**3)** *[Alvis-Carter duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvis%E2%80%93Curtis_duality) should work.*
 It is defind as roughly speaking as follows - take character -  restrict it to  parabolic and than back induction, with summation over all parabolics  with appropriate sign.
The statement is that: it has order two and isometry on generalized characters.
Steinberg representation is dual to trivial. For S_n it is transposition
of Young diagram (if I rember correctly).

**4)** *Frobenius action and Lang-Steiberg theorem.* 
One knows that for F_q there is Frobenius and Lang-Steinberg theorem (e.g. [G.Hiss page 15](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gerhard.Hiss/Presentations/Bath09_Lec1.pdf))
holds that map $G^{-1}F(G)$ is surjection. 
How to define Frobenius ?

**5)** *"Good" bijection between irreducible representation and conjugacy classes (toy Langldands correspondence).*
Similar to [MO270916](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270916/bijection-between-conjugacy-classes-and-irreducible-representation-of-weyl-group) one may expect "good" bijection between conjugacy classes - which might be considered as a toy model for local Langlands correspondence for field with one element. 
For example for S_n there is well-known ["good"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173378/what-is-natural-about-the-well-known-bijection-between-conjugacy-classes-and-irr) bijection between the two sets via Young diagrams.

---

OP made intersting proposal for an $GL(F_{1^n})$ - monomial matrices
with roots of unity entries.
It would be very intersting to check whether the properties above holds true
for such proposal.
What is most unclear for me - what should be Frobenius map ?

Comment: Definition of GL(F_1^n) same as OP's is contained in Kapranov-Smirnov page 4 (middle) http://www.neverendingbooks.org/DATA/KapranovSmirnov.pdf  (Kapranov, Michail; Smirnov, Alexander (1995), Cohomology determinants and reciprocity laws: number field case (PDF))

Comment: Regarding **2)**: Zelevinsky showed (section 7 of his LNM book) that his Hopf algebra methods also apply to  $G\wr S_n$, for fixed (finite) $G$ and varying $n$. The resulting Hopf algebra has one "primitive" (aka "cuspidal") element for each irreducible representation of $G$. So, if we follow @Gro-Tsen and Kapranov-Smirnov and put $GL_n(\mathbb F_{1^m})=\mu_m\wr S_n$, we might interpret Zelevinsky's result as saying that the cuspidal representations of $GL_n(\mathbb F_{1^m})$ are precisely the characters of the "torus" $GL_1(\mathbb F_{1^m})=\mu_m$.

Comment: @t.c. WOW ! WOW ! WOW !

Comment: @t.c. I am happy with the first sentence , however I do not quite  understand the last one

Comment: Sorry, it was indeed quite vague. I am thinking of the following two facts: (1) In Zelevinsky's Hopf algebra $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} K_0(\mathbb C[GL_n(\mathbb F_q)])$, the *primitive* representations (i.e. those $\pi$ such that $\delta(\pi)=\pi\otimes 1 + 1\otimes\pi$, where $\delta$ is the coproduct) are precisely the cuspidal ones (in the usual sense of vanishing under all nontrivial parabolic restrictions). (2) In the Hopf algebra $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} K_0(\mathbb C[G\wr S_n])$, the primitive representations are precisely the irreducible representations of $G\wr S_1$. (to be continued...)

Comment: ...(cont) So, if we accept the analogy "$GL_n(\mathbb F_{1^m}):=\mu_m\wr S_n$", and the analogy "cuspidal representation $:=$ irreducible primitive element of the Zelevinsky Hopf algebra" suggested by fact (1), then fact (2) becomes the assertion that the cuspidal representations of $GL_n(\mathbb F_{1^m})$ are precisely the irreducible representations of $GL_1(\mathbb F_{1^m})$.

Comment: @t.c. WOW ! ( I cannot reply immeadiately - sorry. But your writing is very intresting!)

Comment: In that sense about GL(Fq) : cuspidals also corresponds to charscters of dome tori... but different ... nonsplit ...